# Stats for a Sorcerer King in 4E's Dark Sun?

Tags: dnd-4e, world-building, dark-sun

I am in the middle of building a campaign and part of it takes place in the Athas. I am wanting to present the party with an actual threat towards the end of their stay in the hellacious world of Dark Sun by way of a Sorcerer King. In order to do so, I was wondering if a Sorcerer King had already been stated up (either officially or 3rd party?) I may be decent at encounter building, but am terrible when it comes to building a balanced monster.

Comment: Not an answer, but here's what I'd do. Find a solo controller of appropriate level, reskin it, and use the powers as a guideline to create new ones. 1 at will slide, 1 at will reaction, 1 bloodied reaction, 1 encounter blast + teleport, etc...

Comment: That is a fantastic answer in of itself. Now that's something I can do, reskinning!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Searching the compendium for solo controller leaders as examples gave me a bunch of Sorcerer Kings from the Dark Sun creature catalog!

So, in short, **Yes**, sorcerer-kings have already been given official stats.

- [Andropinis, Sorcerer-King](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/monster.aspx?id=5506) (Level 25 Elite Controller Leader)
- [Dregoth, Sorcerer-King](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/monster.aspx?id=5509) (Level 30 Solo Controller)
- [Hamanu, Sorcerer-King](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/monster.aspx?id=5511) (Level 27 Solo Soldier)
- [Nibenay, Sorcerer-King](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/monster.aspx?id=5521) (Level 29 Elite Controller)
- [Tectuktitlay, Sorcerer-King](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/monster.aspx?id=5524) (Level 22 Elite Artillery Leader)
- [Daskinor, Sorcerer-King](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/monster.aspx?id=5650) (Level 20 Artillery Solo)

Scale the level to your liking and you're good to go!

Comment: This is perfect. I didn't recall seeing any in the Dark Sun CC, but then again, the last time I perused through it was awhile back. I might end up combining your two separate answers into one (ie. build my own using a Solo Controller template with inspiration from the already built SKs)

Comment: On the crossed-out bit: This is what I do regularly in my games -- reskin. I find creatures in the MM or Compendium with the appropriate level and role that I want, then give them wildly different flavor text. Goblins have served as low-level demons, elves as abominations, etc. I also routinely add or swap out powers for my creations, often violating their role to make them fit what I need them to do -- Brutes with pull and reaction powers, for example, normally something associated with Controllers, but it makes them unique -- and more threatening!